# Deployment SAPUI5 Project to SAP NetWeaver JAVA

Tags: sapui5, netweaver

I have already installed *SAP NetWeaver Java Application Server* to deploy a SAPUI5 project but I already find reference link, but not clear. I also search in SAP web but I don't find the document pdf for deployment SAPUI5 project.

Can you give me link reference or link document SAP for deployment SAPUI5 project in SAP NetWeaver JAVA? I already find some reference but I can't implement because the steps is not clear. Can you give me the solution?

Comment: What is the reference you found and what is the exact step you cannot accomplish?

Comment: I use this reference [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/13/developing-sap-ui5-applications-in-netweaver-developer-studio-nwds/)
but the step is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You do it using Netweaver Developer Studio by using an Enterprise Application Project (EAR). Just like any other normal project deployment in NWDS.

Comment: are you have link reference for step deployment?